# Calculation of LineLeft/Right etc

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, scrollviewer

The WPF type `System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer` provides the methods LineLeft(), LineRight(), LineUp() and LineDown().

I want to implement this behavior for a thirt party type which does only support scrolling via ScrollX and ScrollY:

For example:

```
private void MouseWheelChanged(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
   ScrollX += (e.Delta <= 0 ? 50 : -50);
}
```

My question is, if someone knows how LineLeft() etc. calculate the value for scrolling. Is there something like a environment variable or similar available?

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: You can hard-code it like you have, or you can try to find something in the window that has a 'standard' size.  If there's text, get the font size.  You can use that as your delta for both the x and y directions.  You can also say one image is a line, and scroll the height/width of the image, or one row in a table, etc.

Comment: @RyanWH: thanks four your answer! I asked because a team member gave me the advice that on Linux there exists some constant on the system which can be used. ;-)